# Automation For jira - get back previous value of the field

Tags: json, jira

I need to bring back the previous value of the field to this field itself and I'm planning to do it using AUtomation for Jira.
[image]

As you can see automation rule made that field blank (I know why, I've resolved the problem, I just want to bring that value back). I bet there is a way to achieve that using JSON, but I'm not a specialist if it comes to that language. 
[image]
Do you, by any chance, have some experience with it and maybe you could help me? :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "bring back that value" - I'm a little confused as to what exact steps you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ahh, sorry :)
What I mean, is to fill that custom field with a value that was there before Automation for Jira cleared it. SO, on the screen above you can see there was a text "Please review spelling...", Jira deleted it and now that field is empty. 
Probably you are wondering why am I planning to use the next rule to achieve that. I have hundreds of cases I need to do that, this is only one example :)

Comment: I understand, that's what I thought you meant but I needed it confirmed.
My suggestion here would be to use Scriptrunner. Scriptrunner is very simple once you get your head around it and can be very powerful!

This way, in the same script, you can store the previous value as a variable and then reinstate the value after.. I'm happy to write the script to start you off if you need help with it  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you setup "Field value changed" trigger for that field, then you have access to the {{fieldChange}} object.  In there you, you have the "from" and "to" values.  This is not available for all types of trigger events.

[image: Explanation at bottom of event trigger]

I've included an example of how you could prevent a custom field from being manipulated outside of an automation.

[image: Automation only rule beginning]